Postman access vault value in a pre-request script
I'm using Postman v11.14.1
I want to build a postman workspace shared by our team containing requests to some APIs.
I've put all credentials into Postman vault to avoid storing them in a Postman cloud. For example DEV_SYS1_CLIENT_ID, STAGE_SYS1_CLIENT_ID, etc.
Then I've defined our environments: Dev, Stage, etc. Then I define environment variables. For example in Dev: SYS1_CLIENT_ID={{vault:DEV_SYS1_CLIENT_ID}}. For Stage: SYS1_CLIENT_ID={{vault:STAGE_SYS1_CLIENT_ID}}.
Then I have a SOAP API call. Authentication data is part of SOAP request body.
    <soap:Header>
        <auth>
         <clientId>{{SYS1_CLIENT_ID}}</clientId>
         <signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">{{signature}}</signature>
       </auth>
       ...

To calculate the signature value I've created a pre-request script for the Postman collection. It is supposed to use Environment variables to build the signature value.
I use the following method to get Environment variable value:
pm.environment.get("SYS1_CLIENT_ID")

The problem is that the code results in {{vault:DEV_SYS1_CLIENT_ID}} instead of actual value from vault. Can I get actual value there instead of the reference?
Is there another way to inject values built from Vault data into request body? I know that I can set all credentials directly into Environment variables. But I don't think it's a correct way to manage such a data.

I've came up with the following solution.
#1 - enable access to use vault variables in the script sandbox as Danny Dainton suggested above
#2 - write a little helper function to resolve actual secret value instead of {{vault:DEV_SYS1_CLIENT_ID}}:
    const getSecretValue = async (variableName) => {
      const value = pm.environment.get(variableName);       
      if (value && value.startsWith('{{vault:')) {
        const vaultKey = value.substring(8, value.length - 2);
        const vaultValue = await pm.vault.get(vaultKey);
        return vaultValue;
      }
      return value;
    };

#3 Use the function to get actual secret value:
    const clientId = await getSecretValue("SYS1_CLIENT_ID"); 
    // here clientId contains actual secret value, not {{vault:DEV_SYS1_CLIENT_ID}}


You need to first enable access to use vault variables in the script sandbox, this is off by default.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/tests-and-scripts/write-scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-vault-secrets-in-scripts
You can then use pm.vault.get() in the script.
